# Copy all Metadata from Sandbox to Production

Tags: sandbox, change-set, migration, production, unmanaged-package

How do you transfer all setting & metadata (not data) from a sandbox to production?

I have just joined a project which has been tested and approved by the client. My first job is to move everything (only dummy data in the system currently so this isn't important) from the sandbox into production now that it has been signed off.

We have tried using a change set, which didnt feel right as there were so many options to select and it threw errors when we tried to import anyway...

I have been trying to export everything into an unmanaged package, again when I try to import, it throws lots of errors saying things are missing.

I'm struggleing to find an info/process for moving everything over in bulk. Can somone please explain the process for moving and validating everything in a sandbox environment that has been copied to production?

Answer (score 2):

You need the help of a tool. There are many of them out there, some free, some paid.

One example of a paid tool is called [GearSet](https://gearset.com/?gclid=CjwKCAjw5Kv7BRBSEiwAXGDEldKIz8Tp_laXpah7Ux-rrDWfRpnfptJXBL9zz7Odn09MTWZ96rXWuhoCi-cQAvD_BwE). Our migration admin uses this tool to relatively quickly identify differences between two orgs in order to migrate some or all changes. You can also link GearSet to a repository to keep track of those changes, or to deploy missing changes to an org from a repo.

One example of a free tool is [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/) with [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). Using VS Code and the [Salesforce Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode), you can run a diff against files on your computer with an org. You do this by first pulling the data from one org, then using the menu to compare against a different org.

You can also pull down the metadata from both orgs, and simply use the `diff` command-line tool to quickly identify changes in two directories, which in turn would represent the two orgs.

There are [plenty of other solutions](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxSearchKeywordResults?keywords=metadata&searchType=simpleSearch) out there as well. Change Sets and Unmanaged Packages are the bare minimum in functionality and have many limitations. At least with Change Sets, if you can identify the changes you need, you can select them, but this is a very manual process.

Change Sets exist because it was the first attempt at a solution of metadata migration, and it works well for simple changes. You're much better off using a tool built for this purpose.

Please note that you should perform your own product research to determine which solution will solve your problem within your time and cost budgets. I mention GearSet and DX only because those are the tools I'm most familiar with. They are both well-equipped to handle migration tasks, although DX will probably take longer to learn how to use effectively.

You may want to do a search here on SFSE for tips on using DX; several members of our community have written extensive answers on the topic that you may find enlightening.

Comment: Thanks sfdxfox. I've tried using SFDX and successfully retrieved unpackaged.zip using a the package.xml specified [here](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/09/09/xml-package-to-retrieve-metadata-from-org/).
`sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -s -r ./ -u sandbox -k package.xml`

Comment: I then ran the below command but I get lots of errors saying things are missing 

`sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d ./unpackaged -u production-org -w 10 -c`

Comment: @jonny-harte With DX or any tool, you'll still need to compare differences and determine which metadata you need. It's just that some tools are better than other. The best happen to be paid tools, from what I can tell.